# How to open image in full screen by clicking on listview in android tutorial app

Tags: android, listview, imageview

The following is what i got till now. The bug is whenever i click on `ListItem` the following error occurs

> Unfortunately  app has stopped working

**ListViewAdapter.class**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

protected static long[] itemVie;
    // Declare Variables

  Context context;

LayoutInflater inflater;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


ImageLoader imageLoader;


HashMap<String, String> resulta = new HashMap<String, String>();



public ListViewAdapter(Context context,


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {


this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;


imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);


}



@Override


public int getCount() {


return data.size();
    }

    @Override


public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override


public long getItemId(int position) {


    return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables


TextView albname;


ImageView portimages;



inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



View itemVie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position




 resulta = data.get(position);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml


albname = (TextView) itemVie.findViewById(R.id.name);


portimages = (ImageView) itemVie.findViewById(R.id.portImg);


albname.setText(resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_TITLE));


imageLoader.DisplayImage(resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_IMAGE), portimages);





// Capture ListView item click
    itemVie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


resulta = data.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenImage.class);



intent.putExtra("albname", resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_TITLE));
                intent.putExtra("portimages",resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_IMAGE));


context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


return itemVie;
    }
}
```

**FullScreenImage.class**

```
package com.example.truzzapp;
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

ImageView image;
TextView txt;
String port_name;
String port_image;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

       Intent i = getIntent();

 port_name = i.getStringExtra("albname");
```

port_image = i.getStringExtra("portimages");

```
  txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PortHeading);
           image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.portFullImage); 



 txt.setText(port_name);
           imageLoader.DisplayImage(port_image, image);

       }


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

**Logcat error**

```
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.truzzapp/com.example.truzzapp.FullScreenImage} did not call through to super.onCreate()
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-02 13:42:45.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the `logcat` :  `did not call through to super.onCreate()`

You forgot to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` before `setContentView`